# Merge dataframes inside a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and want to merge them inside a function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'A': ['A', 'A']})
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'B': ['B', 'B']})

def func(df):

    dx = df.merge(df_temp, how='left', left_on='col1', right_on='col1')
    return dx

df.pipe(func)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'A': ['A', 'A']})
```

I get the same original df as a result. The column B from df_temp is not being added to the dataframe df as I am expecting. Why this does not work?

Comment: @roganjosh I know I can do this easily outside a function and without using pipe, but this is a small part of a bigger script and it's already set up to use functions and pipe, unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a function that does one, fixed, line of code?

Comment: Well, that was switfly answered :)

Comment: That works, however, most of my function calls are like: ```df.pipe(funct1), df.pipe(func2),..., df.pipe(func17)```. All of them work easily like that, why the function above does not? Is there a way to modify it so I can just call it as ```df.pipe(func)```, and not as ```df = df.pipe(func)```?

Comment: No, you will need to return the value to some name in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign df to the result of the pipe applied function (func).

```
OLD:  df.pipe(func)

NEW:  df=df.pipe(func)
```

Comment: By the pipe documentation, the way to use pipe is```>>> df.pipe(h).pipe(g, arg1=a).pipe(f, arg2=b, arg3=c)
... ```
I am doing that with many other functions but this one does not work like that. Why is the above function different and need to be called as ```df=df.pipe(func)``` instead of ```df.pipe(func) ```

Comment: pipe function does not alter the value of df unless you assign the result to df.  It is like 3 + 1 but you are still printing 3.

Comment: If pipe does not modify df, then we should do ```df = df.pipe(h).pipe(g, arg1=a).pipe(f, arg2=b, arg3=c)``` instead of ```df.pipe(h).pipe(g, arg1=a).pipe(f, arg2=b, arg3=c)```?
The latter was taken from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html

Comment: Yes, we should.